# R bsplus package : bs_tooltip is not working with dateRangeInput/dateInput in Shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny, tooltip

the package `bsplus` is great and easy to use but it seems it doesn't handle dateRangeInput. Is that a bug ?

```
 Error in .tag_validate(tag, name = "div", class = "form-group shiny-input-container") : 
  class is: shiny-date-range-input form-group shiny-input-container, needs to be: form-group shiny-input-container
```

It works perfectly with selectInput and most common inputs

without tooltip it's OK

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
                   start = "2001-01-01",
                   end   = "2010-12-31")    
  )    ,
    selectInput("date", "Date:",
                   choices = c("me","you"))%>%
    shinyInput_label_embed(
      icon("question-circle") %>%
        bs_embed_tooltip(title = "choose your date range dude !")
    )


  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
}
```

with tooltip it doesn't...

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
                   start = "2001-01-01",
                   end   = "2010-12-31")%>%
      shinyInput_label_embed(
        icon("question-circle") %>%
          bs_embed_tooltip(title = "choose your date range dude !")
      )    ,
    selectInput("date", "Date:",
                   choices = c("me","you"))%>%
    shinyInput_label_embed(
      icon("question-circle") %>%
        bs_embed_tooltip(title = "choose your date range dude !")
    )



  )

  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
}
```

It doesn't work with dateInput either...